# How to read this php code?

Tags: php, url, decode

How to decode this string in php?

```
$x = "h\164tp\163\072\057\057\x70r\157\x64\x75\x63t-\x73\x65a\x72\143\150\056\x61\160i\x2e\x63\x6a\x2ec\x6f\x6d\057v\062/\160\x72\157\x64\165\x63t\x2ds\x65\141\162\143\x68\x3f";
```

It looks like a regex URL, but how to read what it is?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks more like a bunch of hex or perhaps a hash. Can you include any of the surrounding code to give context?

Comment: This is not a regex URL. This is an encoded string in another base system. e.g. hex, or something.

Comment: You'll find the code necessary to easily decode this in context of where it is within the page.  Usually... a handful of functions defined to variables.  Simply find where it decodes and echo it from there.

Comment: Hex and octal actually, but close enough.

Comment: reads as `https://product-search.api.cj.com/v2/product-search?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just echo it out.

```
<?
$x = "h\164tp\163\072\057\057\x70r\157\x64\x75\x63t-\x73\x65a\x72\143\150\056\x61\160i\x2e\x63\x6a\x2ec\x6f\x6d\057v\062/\160\x72\157\x64\165\x63t\x2ds\x65\141\162\143\x68\x3f";
echo $x;
```

It outputs:

```
https://product-search.api.cj.com/v2/product-search?
```

Comment: Ha.., you guys are good. I am a .net programmer, new to php. Did not thought about simply echo it out.

Answer (score 3):

Print it!

```
% cat test.php 
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php
$x = "h\164tp\163\072\057\057\x70r\157\x64\x75\x63t-\x73\x65a\x72\143\150\056\x61\160i\x2e\x63\x6a\x2ec\x6f\x6d\057v\062/\160\x72\157\x64\165\x63t\x2ds\x65\141\162\143\x68\x3f";
print $x;
?>

% ./test.php
https://product-search.api.cj.com/v2/product-search?
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a string with some characters specified in hexadecimal and octal notation. Just echo it.

Answer (score 0):

just print it, its a url

https://product-search.api.cj.com/v2/product-search?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I created a PHP page as follows:

```
<?php
$x = "h\164tp\163\072\057\057\x70r\157\x64\x75\x63t-\x73\x65a\x72\143\150\056\x61\160i\x2e\x63\x6a\x2ec\x6f\x6d\057v\062/\160\x72\157\x64\165\x63t\x2ds\x65\141\162\143\x68\x3f";

print $x;
?>
```

and ran it.

And I got the following:

```
https://product-search.api.cj.com/v2/product-search?
```

Which means nothing to me, except that cj.com is part of Commission Junction, which is an online advertising network.

It's been deliberately obfuscated, so clearly the person who wrote it intended that you didn't notice it or understand it, and would leave it alone. I don't know the context of the question, why you're asking about it, but my guess would be that you've been hacked and someone has inserted this code (and more) into your site.

If that's the case, their aim would clearly be to gain some advertising revenue by freeloading on your site. Not particularly malicious as hacks go, but not something you'd want to be happening (especially if you don't know what kind of ads would be shown).

Comment: That must be it. No wonder my site sometimes acts werid recently. I got to figure out how to chean it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
utf8_decode();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php